# Key-code to relaunch the minimised application Android

Tags: selenium, appium

Can someone tell me what is the keycode to re-launch the minimised application in android i used the following code to minimise the app.

```
((AndroidDriver<?>) getDriver()).pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.HOME);
```

Answer (score 0):

Appium already has `driver.launchApp();` method to reopen closed app.